# Maintain access to folders and files across application sessions using .NET MAUI

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

For my cross-platform .NET MAUI **desktop** application I want the user to pick a location to save their data, ideally with them picking a folder that is synchronized to the cloud for backup, like OneDrive.

The application will let them open files from any folder and retain a link to it to open it again in the future.

So over time I need to re-open data files stored in a given folder and re-open files that can be scattered across the file system.

For this I would use the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit FolderPicker, FileSaver and built in FilePicker.

It is my understanding that the folder and file permissions granted to the application do not persist across application sessions.

What do I need to do to make sure the user is not bombarded with file and folder permission requests every time they use the application?  Or even worse, there is no future permission request and it just fails.

Comment: `It is my understanding` - have you tested this assumption?

Comment: This is why I am asking the question.  I don’t want to spend many hours trying to get this working if someone already knows the answer.

Avalonia has recently added some support but it’s missing for MacOS.

Comment: it seems like this is something you could easily test in 15 minutes

Comment: I have a MacOs desktop application and I have a situation where access to folder is not working unless I choose the folder again, so I backup this question as valid.

Comment: It seems to be the problem is that MAUI does not have any support for storage bookmarks. You have to code all this yourself to each platform if you want to sandbox your app.  Avalonia is in the process of adding this.

https://www.mergeconflict.fm/296

Comment: I have started a discussion over on MAUI Community Toolkit as well.  https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/discussions/1548